# Convert rows to columns on Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two columns (Name and Gender). There are 4 records in my table.

```
Name  Gender
A       Male
B       Female
C       Male
D       Female
```

I would like to write a SQL Query to convert the above data to below format.

```
Male      Female
A           B    
C           D
```

Comment: Why do you want to match unrelated data?

Comment: Could you explain more about expected result? What logic that output is `A-B` not `A-D`? What's expected output if we have 1 (2, 3, ...) more row e.g `E Female`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option, using CTEs:

```
WITH male AS (
    SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Gender = 'Male'
),
female AS (
    SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Gender = 'Female'
)

SELECT m.Name AS Male, f.Name AS Female
FROM male m
INNER JOIN female f
    ON m.rn = f.rn;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility similar to Tim's but only requires a single CTE:

```
with numbered as (
   select name, gender, row_number() over (partition by gender order by name) as rn
   from the_table
)
select f.name as "Female", m.name as "Male"
from numbered f 
  full outer join numbered m on m.rn = f.rn and m.gender = 'Male'
where f.gender = 'Female';
```

By using a full outer join this also works if there is a different number of rows per gender.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f917f937e79a56b5b20d583bb943da98)

Comment: But what about multiple genders per person :P ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: that wouldn't change anything in the output. The query only takes into account Male and Female. If by chance there are more genders, those would generate additional partitions in the window function which would simply never be used due to the filters in the join condition and the where. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=78f3a0f3c948a459e5f7157d595d90cf

Comment: I was making a joke in that comment.  Your answer is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as that:

```
SELECT m.Name Male, f.Name Female
FROM t m, t f
WHERE m.Gender = "Male" AND f.Gender = "Female";
```

But it doesn't make much sense, I hope you know what you're doing.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. This takes me close to my answer except 4 rows instead of 2. I see the 2 correct rows and 2 incorrect rows.